# About the polarization tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen that a tag *polarization* exists. There is no definition associated with it. Unfortunately, it refers to a lot of different mechanisms, almost all of them having to do with classical electromagnetism, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization for instance.

Can we fix this problem ?

Of course, most of the time the meaning is clear from the context. But it's still unsatisfactory, isn't it ?

I mean, can we decide which tag's definition is the best ? I would vote for Polarization in the sense of light polarisation, like in this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves) And Maybe add a tag Polarizability for the creation of dipolar moment ? Or keep the tag Dipole moment (which already exists) for this last one ?

Are you ok with this ? (vote up if you are for instance, or comment)

Comment: There's a general feeling that new tags should only be created with good reason, so perhaps hold off on [tag:polarizability] for now? Fortunately, it appears most of the questions already tagged [tag:polarization] are indeed about photons and not induced dipoles or vacuum polarizations.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and are encouraged to: there's [a badge for that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/53/tag-editor)) suggest a text for tag wikis.

Click the badge, then click the "help us create it?" link in the box at the top of the page.

Why don't you give us a definition?

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I wanted to say. I wanted to ask you "Which definition to use for the tag Polarization ?" I would personally push in favor of light polarisation, i.e. this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves) one

Comment: "[All registered users can submit edits for tag wikis](http://physics.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)"

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisWhite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, done. Needs a referring.
Thanks for your participation.